# Kivy poor performance on Samsung Exynos5422 w/ Mali-T628 MP6

Tags: python, linux, arm, kivy, mali

I'm developing an app with Python and I use "Kivy" to create UI. On windows with Intel CPU and nVidia GPU machine everything goes as expected but on Ubuntu and Android machines with ARM CPU and Mali GPU the performance is very very poor, i.e: 1sec animation/transition takes several second and lags every single frame, another example: when I click/tap on buttons even background change takes some time!!!
How can I fix it? Thank you in advance

Comment: Without some example as to what you are trying it's rather hard to help. Most of us lack psychic powers ...

The most obvious answer is that you are trying to do too much work per frame - desktop GPUs have orders of magnitude more processing power than a mobile GPU.

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to answer without first understanding the device/platform, the hardware, the exact chipset in your device/platform (there are many different ARM chipsets out there), the exact operating system and software environment, and the configurations of each of these on your particular device.

I personally have not used Kivy but in general I suggest trying to have a very simple program and assessing or comparing that with your desktop environment.
If this shows a very bad performance then you know the issue is in the frameworks and libraries that you have used. If a simple application does not show any issues then you can move on to adding more complex components and more UI elements until you can see what causes the performance issues.

When it comes to performance issues on graphics applications, the first question to answer is whether the bottleneck is the CPU or the GPU. Depending on the answer your approach to fixing your issues will be different.

The frameworks that you use (Python+Kivy) can have a big impact. Newer mobile devices these days are usually very powerful often with multiple CPU and GPU cores running at high frequencies (often 1GHz+). However, if the frameworks are not well optimised for your particular platform (and the particular configuration of your device) then they may perform really bad. So I also suggest that you make sure these frameworks and libraries are optimised for your target device (Are there any other Apps that use these frameworks and perform well?).

You could also try and do some performance monitoring to find out whether it is the CPU or the GPU which is causing the issue and to find out what part of the software stack is causing this issue. Doing this needs a little bit of experience of developing graphics applications for mobile devices but you can take a look at some resources available from ARM to help you investigate potential issues.

You could use the ARM DS-5 and ARM STREAMLINE PERFORMANCE ANALYSER along with a number of tools from ARM MALI DEVELOPER CENTER:

http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/

http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/tools/software-tools/

Comment: I found that the vendor's OS have some driver issues with the GPU, so it uses software rasterizer (CPU) instead. I tried other versions of Linux but no luck so far. However I gave up on that board for now, hope to find some solution. Thank you for your answer. PS. I mentioned the CPU/GPU model in the title.

Comment: The CPU/GPU model are needed to help fix such issues but the specific board and the vendor are also important. This is because the same CPU and GPU can operate very differently from one board to another board, especially when used with different builds and configurations of Linux and/or Android. It is best to try your applications on a number of different boards to see if it works better on any other platform.